# textContent Material Designer Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Estou usando o Dialog do Material AngularJS e está tudo bem, mas quando coloco o `textContent` ele retorna o seguinte erro:

**CONSOLE ERROR**

```
 $mdDialog.confirm(...).title(...).textContent is not a function
```

**JS**

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
              .title('Você tem certeza que deseja excluir esta categoria?')
              .textContent('Esta ação é irreversível')
              .ariaLabel('Excluir')
              .targetEvent(ev)
              .ok('Sim tenho certeza!')
              .cancel('Não excluir');

        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
            // ok
        }, function() {
          // cancelado
        });
```

Por que este `textContent` não está aceito? O exemplo é o mesmo do Angular JS Material.

Comment: Seu AngularJS/Material é a mesma versão do exemplo no site?

Comment: Provavelmente você está usando uma versão que não suporta o `.textContent`

Comment: Sim eu estava com uma versão anterior, estou me acostumando com a mudança que o Angular tem seguidamente rs

Comment: @user3801617 se prepare pra mais mudanças, Angular 2.0 está chegando rs. Resolveu o problema?

Comment: @Shelon *In all fairness*, quem mudou foi o mdDialog, não o AngularJS em si. Mas Techies está plenamente correto, 2.0 é completamente diferente. =)

Comment: @Techies Tudo resolvido, Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

A versão que você está usando provavelmente é anterior a 1.0.0, Nas versões anteriores ao invés de `textContent` a função se chamava apenas `content`.

Você pode seguir os exemplos do site oficial conforme a versão que está usando, apenas altere onde mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: +1 pela imagem bonitinha. Só complementando, acho que da pra você utilizar `content` no lugar de `textContent`. Vi isso graças a resposta do @devgaspa